# How to remove cell content in excel using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to remove the cell content but keeping its style but it's always remove the style and content. Here's my code:

```
private static void RefreshReport(String sheetName, String resultColumn) {
        try {
            InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(getExcelFile());
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
            int colResult = getColumnResult(sheet, resultColumn);
            int rowStart = getRowResult(sheet, resultColumn);
            int rowEnd = Math.max(20, sheet.getLastRowNum());
            for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
                Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
                if (r != null) {
                    Cell cell = r.createCell(colResult);
                    if (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                        CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
                        cs = cell.getCellStyle();
                        r.removeCell(cell);
                        cell = r.createCell(colResult);
                        cell.setCellStyle(cs);
                    }
                }
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(getExcelFile());
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            inp.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is your problem then... Please share what you want which this code is not able to do...

Comment: @Sankumarsingh I want to delete the content of Cell but keeping its style.

Comment: I'm just wondering why don't you just set the cell value instead of removing it ?

Comment: @zawhtut set cell value will remove the cell style too

Comment: That does not sound right, but if true: pull the style out, set the content, and set the style again from where you have stored it temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that your method isn't working is that you are always calling `createCell` if the the row `r` is not `null`.  This will overwrite any `Cell` that already exists, including contents and styling.

What you need to do is call `getCell` instead.  This will retrieve the `Cell` at that column index, provided it exists, or `null` if it doesn't exist.  Then if it exists, you can process the `Cell` as you are doing.

```
if (r != null) {
   Cell cell = r.getCell(colResult);
   if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() != CellType.BLANK) {
       // rest of your code here
```

In an alternative to the delete/re-create method you have, you can just set the cell type to `BLANK`.  This will set the contents to blank, but it will also preserve the cell style currently on that cell.  There is no need to delete the cell and re-create it.

```
if (cell.getCellType() != CellType.BLANK) {
   cell.setCellType(CellType.BLANK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to the rgettman's comment.
But in POI 5.0, you should use cell.setBlank() instead, because cell.setCellType(CellType.BLANK) is deprecated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).